# How to check all columns data types of table using AWK script?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, types, scripting

Here I'm checking the data type of first column in the table. But I want to know all columns data type of the table in AWK. I tried but I can get only one columns data type.

For example:

Column_1 int

Column_2 int

Column_3 Char

Column_4 Symbol

```
BEGIN{
        FS=","
}

{
             if($1~ "^[0-9][0-9]*$" ) type="int";
                 else if($1~ "^[a-zA-Z][a-z[A-Z]*$") type="char";
                                 else type="symbol";
                                         print $1" ",type;
         }
```

Comment: Good that you have shown your code/attempts, please do share samples of input and expected output also in your question to make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`xx*` is BRE syntax for `x+` ERE syntax which awk supports. I don't think you intend to have `[` in the middle of `[a-z[A-Z]`. You may want to change `char` to `alpha` since everything's a `char`. The regexp delimiter is `/`, not `"`.

Try this:

```
BEGIN {
        FS=","; OFS="  "
}

{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if      ( $i ~ /^[0-9]+$/ )    type="int"
        else if ( $i ~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ ) type="alpha"
        else                           type="symbol"
        print $i, type
    }
}
```

Also consider using POSIX character classes like `[:alpha:]` instead of hard-coding ranges like `a-zA-Z`.

The above is untested since you didn't provide sample input nor expected output in your question, nor did you tell us what you'd want the output to look like for multiple fields per line input.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this Awk approach (more than `if ... then ... else...` structure):

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}

$1 ~ /^[0-9][0-9]*$/       { print $1, "int"  ; next}
$1 ~ /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*$/ { print $1, "char" ; next}
{ print $1, "symbol" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU `AWK` you might prepare [`function`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Function-Example.html) and then use `for` to apply it for each field as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
123 HELLO ???
```

then

```
awk 'function whatisit(x){if(x~"^[0-9][0-9]*$"){return "int"};if(x~"^[a-zA-Z][a-z[A-Z]*$"){return "char"};return "symbol"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){print i,whatisit($i)}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1 int
2 char
3 symbol
```

Explanation: define function named `whatisit` accepting single argument and implementing described detection logic, note that no `else` is requires as `return` terminates function execution. For each line iterate over available field using three-argument for (initialization, check, action after loop turn) `print`ing number of each field followed by detected type.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*