# How to check data type of each column in AWK script?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, types

In python we have function called [dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) in pandas, It will show the data type of each column. In AWK we can read and do some data processing works. but I can't check data type of each column. In Awk, it take data in row by row order, not in column level.

```
    BEGIN{
    FS=",";
    
}

function whatisit(x){
        if(x~"^[0-9][0-9]*$")
            {return "int"};
        if(x~"^[a-zA-Z][a-z[A-Z]*$")
            {return "char"};
        return "symbol"}
        
{print $0"--->"whatisit($0)}
```

It will produce the out like this:

```
:~/AWK$ awk -f bin.awk sample.csv
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5--->symbol
1,a,aad,24,10.3--->symbol
2,b,sdsf,90,84.2--->symbol
3,c,dfd,28,84.2--->symbol
4,d,dhj,29,10.4--->symbol
5,e,kae,19,30.4--->symbol
6,f,IEF,93,83.1--->symbol
```

But I expect:

```
  :~/AWK$ awk -f bin.awk sample.csv
  c1 --> int
  c2 --> char
  c3 --> char
  c4 --> int
  c5 --> float
```

The sample.csv file is :

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
1,a,aad,24,10.3
2,b,sdsf,90,84.2
3,c,dfd,28,84.2
4,d,dhj,29,10.4
5,e,kae,19,30.4
6,f,IEF,93,83.1
```

Please anyone help me out !!

Comment: So can any value in between be different for any column? Lets say first column can have string also apart from integers?

Comment: That is column name !!!

Comment: `$0` denotes the **whole line**. Of course, the whole line is classified as a _symbol_, not the least because it contains  commas as field separator and `whatisit` spits out _symbol_, if it receives a string containing a comma.

Comment: In fact, 2 of the answers to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72948656/1745001), including [the one you copied that `whatisit` function from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72950514/1745001), show you the answer to this question as they loop on the fields.

Comment: You say you expect `c5 --> float` in your output but there's nothing in your code to attempt to identify a float and your question is just about testing fields instead of whole records.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the fields and call your function separately on each.

```
awk -F "," 'function whatisit () { ... }
NR==1 { split($0, col); next }
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
   print col[i], whatisit($i)
  exit }' file
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/c7yCvd

This will only examine the second line of data. If you want to examine all rows, you'll need to figure out some sort of resolution hierarchy so that for example strings which happen to contain only numbers get resolved into strings if the same field on another line contains nonnumeric data.

However, Awk may not be ideal for a general-purpose solution as it is not particularly equipped to cope with quoting and other nitty-gritty details of the CSV format. I'd stick to Python, which includes a proper `csv` parser in its standard library.
[Determine data type from CSV - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072285/determine-data-type-from-csv-python) has solutions without Pandas, which is a heavy third-party dependency you might want to avoid.